# How to solve MongoError: no primary found in replicaset

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running a node js application in Windows with MongoDB (version 3.4) as its database. It was running fine before I suddenly got this error while running the node js server:

```
MongoError: no primary found in replicaset
at C:\Users\common\server\nodeapp\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:524:28
```

And in the windows command prompt where I started mongo db with command mongod, showing the below messages at the end :

```
2017-01-12T21:02:30.286+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53591 #3 (3 connections now open)
2017-01-12T21:02:30.294+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53592 #4 (4 connections now open)
2017-01-12T21:02:30.320+0530 I -        [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:53592 (4 connections now open)
2017-01-12T21:02:30.321+0530 I -        [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:53590 (4 connections now open)
2017-01-12T21:02:30.321+0530 I -        [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:53591 (4 connections now open)
```

I uninstalled Mongo DB and installed it again and created the data/db directory all over again, but the problem still persists. Could you please suggest a solution ?

Comment: do you have replica set running on your local machine? whats the connection string looks like?

Comment: Just to add, with every time I try to start the node js application, the number of connections open are increasing by 1 in the windows command prompt when mongo db was started .. and another error which is also coming in node js editor terminal is : C:\Users\common\server\nodeapp\node_modules\mongodb\lib\replset.js:362
          process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                        ^

Comment: @Astro the connection string looks like :  mongoose.connect("localhost", "nodeapp", 27017);

Comment: whats the nodeapp? in connect

Comment: @Astro that's my node js application

Comment: is it correct? Shoudn't it be like? mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp'); where myapp is db name

Comment: @Astro am getting the same error even if I change it to the one you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138352/discussion-between-astro-and-a-g-progm-enthusiast).